# How to get a max value of a column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the max value of a column. I have the following table structure:

```
OrderID | TaskID  | SerialNo
1       |   1     |   1
1       |   1     |   2
1       |   2     |   1
1       |   2     |   2
1       |   2     |   3
2       |   1     |   1
2       |   2     |   1
2       |   2     |   2
```

From the above table I want the following result for every `OrderID` and `TaskID`, display the max value:

```
SerialNo
2
3
1
2
```

By using `MAX` I am getting the `OrderID` and `TaskID` as well, which is not my intended result. I am using SQL Server. How would I get the intended result?

Comment: This sure looks familiar....http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1698667-1292-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select OrderId, TaskId, max(SerialNo)
from MyTable
group by OrderId, TaskId
```

If you really only want the `max(SerialNo)`, you can omit the other two columns in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
SELECT MAX(SerialNo) AS SerialNo
FROM TableName
GROUP BY OrderID, TaskID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `max` value, you could just eliminate other two columns from your `select` statement like this:

```
SELECT MAX(SerialNo) AS SerialNo
FROM test
GROUP BY OrderID, TaskID
ORDER BY OrderID, TaskID --added order by to precisely replicate your output above
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3e73/3/0)